# How to express "suspended flowers" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'm currently working on a German text. I need to translate "suspended flowers" into German. When I used my dictionary the most suitable translations was "hängende Blumen" but I don't think that's the right way to express it.

I'm trying to describe the time when I was visiting a cave. What I want to say:

> At the entrance there were suspended flowers besides the stalagmites.

What I have so far:

> Am Eingang waren neben den Stalagmiten *hängende Blumen.*

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? Maybe you can give us more context. At least a complete sentence would be fine.

Comment: I'm trying to describe the time when I was visiting a cave. What I want to say: `At The entrance there were suspended flowers besides the stalagmites.` What I have so far: `Am Eingang waren neben den Stalagmiten ?hängende Blumen?.`

Comment: It's probably even more right than in English: *suspended* IMHO implies that has been done to them artificially, while "hängend" just means they're hanging down from somewhere.

Comment: @tofro really? That's good to know then! Thank you.

Comment: And you can change it into a verb: Am Eingang hingen Blumen neben den Stalagmiten" or "... hingen neben den Stalagmiten Blumen", depending on intended emphasis. "... waren hängende Blumen" sounds artificial.

Comment: You could have edited your question. I did it for you.

Comment: Perhaps _herunterhängend_ might make it clearer what you would like to say, but I cannot look into your mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence

> Am Eingang waren neben den Stalagmiten *hängende Blumen.*

is absolutely correct.

You can find possible translations for »*hängend*« here: [http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/hängend](http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/h%C3%A4ngend)

The word »*hängend*« is a participle (i.e. can be used as an adjective or as a verb) and is derived from the verb »*hängen*« (you'll find translations on dict.leo.org too).

Answer (score 4):

We have compound nouns

> Hängeblumen, [Hängepflanzen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/H%C3%A4ngepflanze)

but these do not quite catch the artificial decorative nature of *suspended flowers* as they are more terms for describing the growth pattern of some plants.

We therefore may need to explain the term while translating:

> Der Eingang neben den Stalagmiten war mit hängenden Blumen verziert.
>   Neben den Stalagmiten hingen [Blumenampeln](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/Blumenampel) am Eingang.
>   Den Eingang neben den Stalagmiten verzierten Hängepflanzen.

Comment: *Blumenampeln* is definitly artificial, while *suspended flowers* might or might not be made by man.

Comment: @tofro Apparently *suspended flowers* are more artificial than *hanging flowers*. For something to be *suspended* (= "aufgehängt") a voluntary action by man is required.

Comment: See OP's answer to my comment above. Apparently, he likes it natural.